# Launching an application in Java through a Process without closing the parent application?

Tags: java, process, runtime

I'm trying to launch the League Of Legends application through Java and it works but in order for it to get over the League Of Legends loading logo, I need to close the parent application,

Here is the code for running it:

```
File dir = new File("C:/Riot Games/League of Legends/RADS/solutions/lol_game_client_sln/releases/0.0.1.110/deploy/");
                    String[] cmd = new String[] {
                                dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "League of Legends.exe",
                                "8394",
                                "LoLLauncher.exe",
                                "\"\"",
                                "spectator spectator.na.lol.riotgames.com:80 " + currentGame.getObservers().getEncryptionKey() + " " + currentGame.getGameId() + " NA1"};
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, dir);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

It just says Not Responding if the parent application is still open, immediately after I close the parent application, it starts loading and works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that LOL is dumping huge amounts of data out of it's stdio streams, and you are not eating them from your process object. You may need to start a thread that just sits and gulps down stuff that shows up in Process.getInputStream() or Process.getErrorStream

Comment: I used a StreamGobbler I found and inputted the input and error streams into it and it worked like magic! Thanks for the help